# element.addEventListener ejecuta la función al cargar la página

Tags: javascript, eventos

Ya estuve leyendo al respecto y encontré el siguiente código:

```
var formulario = document.getElementById("miForm");
formulario.addEventListener("submit", llamar);

function llamar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Presionado");
}
```

Al parecer dentro de los parámetros de `addEventListener()`, si el nombre de la función va con paréntesis es como estarla llamando y es por eso que no espera hasta que ocurra el evento para ejecutarse sino que lo hace al cargar la página; el problema es que mi función necesita parámetros y si no usara `functionName('value1', 'value2'...)` ¿Cómo  podría pasárselos? Además en el ejemplo de arriba, leí que para usar `preventDefault()` se necesita un evento, el cual no veo que esté definido ya que, de nuevo, no se le están pasando parámetros a `functionName`.

PD: Mi función está almacenada como propiedad de un objeto y los parámetros se le pasan basadas en otras propiedades del mismo, no sé si eso afecte a una posible solución.

Answer (score 3):

Lo típico es hacer algo como

```
var formulario = document.getElementById("miForm");
function llamar(event, p1,p2) { ... }

formulario.addEventListener("submit", event => llamar(event, 'value1', 'value2'...));
```

De este modo pasas los valores que quieras a la función, anidando su llamada. Otra forma similar de resolverlo es así:

```js
let botones = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function generaFuncion(parametro) {
  return function (evento) {
    console.log('Has pulsado el botón', evento.currentTarget.innerHTML);
    console.log('Tengo el parámetro', parametro);    
  };
}

botones.forEach((boton, indice) => {
  boton.addEventListener("click", generaFuncion(indice));
});
```

```html
<button> Click 1</button>
<button> Click 2</button>
<button> Click 3</button>
<button> Click 4</button>
```

Es decir, tienes una función que genera dinámicamente funciones que recibirán los parámetros que pases a la generadora, con una clausura.

Answer (score 1):

> PD: Mi función está almacenada como propiedad de un objeto y los parámetros se le pasan basadas en otras propiedades del mismo, no sé si eso afecte a una posible solución.

En el ejemplo que presentas no se ve una configuración Object, lo que yo sugiero es usar `bind`, esto para asegurarte de no perder el contexto de ejecución, al usar `bind` **el evento se pasa implícitamente en los argumentos**.

```
formulario.addEventListener("submit", llamar.bind(this, 'value1', 'value2'));

function llamar(e, param1, param2) {
   console.log(e);
   console.log(param1);
   console.log(param2);
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("Presionado");
}
```